# Configure Grunt Clean Task

Tags: gruntjs

I am using the [gruntfile.js associated with Steroids.js](https://github.com/AppGyver/grunt-steroids/blob/master/Gruntfile.js). From my understanding, that file uses grunt-contrib-clean to clean up stuff between builds. That task effectively deletes the `dist` directory.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to configure this task so that the contents of `dist` are deleted, but not the directory itself. Is this possible? If so, how? The reason I need to do this is because I have IIS pointing at the `dist` directory for testing purposes. However, the build fails because IIS locks the `dist` directory, preventing it from being deleted. That's why I want to delete the contents of `dist` instead of the directory itself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
clean: {
  dist: {
    src: "dist/**/*"
  }
}
```

In this case you need to modify the file at `tasks/steroids-clean-dist.coffee`.